# Mortar washout on brick

Tags: exterior, brick, siding, mortar

Moved into a home and looks as if when the retaining wall was installed they allowed the mortar to washout and stain the bricks. What we are left with is a very ugly street facing wall. Not great for curb appeal and want to repair. Anyone can confirm that this is what happened and way to repair? Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: I'd guess there used to be a different retaining wall here that was tied into the brick and they replaced it with your allen block wall which is probably not mortared at all.  is there a gap between the allen block and the brick?  what does the other side look like?  take another picture so we can see the left / right symmetry

Comment: Yes used to be an older retaining wall. Most likely what it is. There is a slight gap.

Comment: That retaining wall looks decades older than the house wall. It looks more like the house wall was badly patched. Is that actually brick-built or is it a veneer?

Comment: I'd be tempted to slide a large piece of white flashing between the allen blocks and the brick and follow the vertical line of the brick separation but this depends on what the other side looks like

Comment: Hi - I believe it’s veneer. It has been raining a lot so looks dark like that. Home was built in ‘58 - retaining wall is less than 10 years old

Comment: @FreshCodemonger - there is no 'other side of the wall' to look at. It's a retaining wall, earth-backed. It doesn't look at all like wash-out to me, it looks like someone has punched a hole [or two] & patched it. There's not even any 'brick shape' there on the two worst bits. We do need to see a wider shot to tell how new the patch looks against the rest. Right now we can see bits of what looks like older martar, but not enough to guess at.

Comment: That mortar just looks too clean for '58. 65 years… nope.

Comment: @testsujin I want to see the other side of the door, if you trim the left side with flashing you might want to trim the right side too.  My guess is that this is a walk out to a basement that was added after the house, the original walkout retaining wall that was put in at same time as brick was replaced with an allen block wall and patched poorly where the old retaining wall hooked into the brick.  allen block walls quickly age and look old like this one - 10 years doesn't surprise me.  i'd agree that the brick veneer here isn't original.

Comment: This is the driveway. The black is the garage door

Comment: Probably where the old retaining wall hooked into the brick. So how does one go about repairing the look?

Comment: My best guess is the veneer is actually missing behind a lot of that cement. Pretty much anything you do now will involve new veneer [which will be tough to match].

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, nobody can really tell what's going on under there. Start out by pressure cleaning that corner and then scrape the mortar with a scraper or chisel to remove the thick mortar. Then you can use some muriatic acid to remove the rest of the mortar from the bricks. Test first in a hidden area. Hopefully, you'll find that the bricks go all the way to the wall. Once cleaned up, you'll want tp seal the area, neatly, between the retaining wall and the brick wall. An epoxy sealer or grout might work well.